# VBA Match function using today's date to search for last year's entry

Tags: vba, excel, date

So say I got Today's date `=TODAY()` and two matrixes with sales arranged by date.

```
Date      Store1  Store2  
1/11/2017  800    2000  
2/11/2017  500    3000
```

and

```
Date       Store1  Store2  
1/11/2016   400     5000  
2/11/2016   2000    6000
```

I'm trying to calculate how much sales increased on a date compared to last year's but I cant find any way that works.

```
Date       IncreaseStore1 IncreaseStore2  
1/11  
2/11
```

I found this Function to get last year's date but it gives me the date as text and I cant find a way to fix it with VBA.

```
Function PrevYear(XYear As Date) As String

    PrevYear = Format(Format(XYear, "dd/mm") & "/" & Format(XYear, "yyyy") - 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")

End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated since I'm all out of ideas

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear. Here is a function that returns a date rather than a string.

```
Function PrevYear(XYear As Date) As Date
    PrevYear = DateAdd("YYYY", -1, XYear)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you want to use VBA? You can do this easily enough with formulas using this:

```
 =DATE(YEAR(A2)-1,MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))
```

Using VBA:

```
DateAdd("YYYY",-1,Range("A2"))
```